# Not working firefox web browser (zombie) in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-10.10

I use Firefox browser in Ubuntu 10.10, but now it doesn't work. When I try to open the browser, an error message is displayed with the following content

> Close Firefox Firefox is already running but is not responding. To
>   open new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or
>   restart your system.

Then I restart the system but again it doesn't work. Then I watch the task manager and I see that zombie is written in the same line as firefox like shown in the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/228063).

- It seems your system might not be up-to-date.
- You could be stuck in the middle of some upgrade.
- There could be system (memory or hard-disk) issues.
- Check you /var/log/syslog
- Try upgrading to Firefox's latest version.